# SQL Query and Excel

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

I'm using an SQL query in EXCEL to display data.

My problem is that there are over 150 rows and i need to split this to so 75 side by side.

The number of rows will vary from week to week but will never go past 300.

If i cut and paste then when i reload the data it just joins on to the end of Query 1.

Any suggestions?

Here is the example code -

```
SELECT
    worksorders.id AS 'Works ID',        
    worksorders.partid AS Part, 
    allpartmaster.partdesc AS Description, 
    machines.macdesc AS Machine, 
    worksorders.quantity AS Qty, 
    worksorders.quantitycompleted AS 'Qty Comp',
    (worksorders.quantitycompleted/worksorders.quantity)*100 AS Percentage, 
    worksorders.isroutecardprinted AS 'Printed?'
FROM           
worksorders INNER JOIN
allpartmaster ON worksorders.partid = allpartmaster.partnum INNER JOIN
routingoperations ON worksorders.partid = routingoperations.partid INNER JOIN
machines ON routingoperations.workcentreid = machines.macid
WHERE        
(worksorders.status IN ('ACTIVE')) 
AND
(worksorders.quantitycompleted < worksorders.quantity)
AND 
(allpartmaster.prodgroup LIKE 'Welding')
AND
(allpartmaster.partdesc not like '%base%')
AND
(allpartmaster.partdesc not like '%hinge%')
AND
(worksorders.id not like '%OH%')
AND
worksorders.createddate BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, - 14, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(dd, 14, GETDATE())
ORDER BY 
worksorders.id ASC
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Give some code and some screenshots, the chances to get good help get better with the quality of the question.

Comment: Use sql to get the data.  Use VBA to do things with it afterwards.

Comment: Hi Dan. Have you got an example of this?